# C char array overflow, okay practice?

Tags: c

I'm going through the K & R book and the answer to one of the exercises is troubling me.

In the solutions manual, exercise 1-22 declares a char array:

```
#define MAXCOL 10
char line[MAXCOL];
```

so my understanding is that in C arrays go from 0 ... n-1. If that's the case then the above declaration should allocate memory for a char array of length 10 starting with 0 and ending with 9. More to the point line[10] is out of bounds according to my understanding? A function in the sample program is eventually passed a integer value pos that is equal to 10 and the following comparison takes place:

```
int findblnk(int pos) {
while(pos > 0 && line[pos] != ' ')
        --pos;
    if (pos == 0)                   //no blanks in line ?
        return MAXCOL;
    else                        //at least one blank
        return pos+1;               //position after blank
}
```

If pos is 10 and line[] is only of length 10, then isn't line[pos] out of bounds for the array?

Is it okay to make comparisons this way in C, or could this potentially lead to a segmentation fault? I am sure the solutions manual is right this just really confused me. Also I can post the entire program if necessary. Thanks!

Thanks for the speedy and very helpful responses, I guess it is definitely a bug then. It is called through the following branch:

```
else if (++pos >= MAXCOL) {
            pos = findblnk(pos);
            printl(pos);
            pos = newpos(pos);
        }
```

MAXCOL is defined as 10 as stated above. So for this branch findblnk(pos) pos would be passed 10 as a minimum.

Do you think the solution manual for K & R is worth going through or is it known for having buggy code examples?

Comment: Note that the address `pos[10]` is guaranteed to be OK (it will be valid, and one byte beyond `pos[9]`).  Trying to access the value at `pos[10]`, either to read or write it, is undefined behaviour.  Anything could happen when you invoke undefined behaviour, including 'it seems to work' or 'the computer crashes' or ...

Answer (score 3):

It is *never*, **ever** okay to over-run the bounds of an array in C. (Or any language really).

If 10 is really passed to that function, that is certainly a bug.  While there are better ways of doing it, that function should at least verify that `pos` is within the bounds of `line` before attempting to use it as an index.

Answer (score 3):

If `pos` is indeed `10` then it would be an out of bounds access and accessing an array out of bounds is [undefined behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) and therefore anything can happen even a program that appears to work properly at the time, the results are unreliable. The draft C99 standard `Annex J.2` *undefined behavior* contains the follows bullet:

> An array subscript is out of range, even if an object is apparently accessible with the
>   given subscript (as in the lvalue expression a[1][7] given the declaration int
>   a[4][5]) (6.5.6).

I don't have a copy of *K&R* handy but the [errata](http://cm.bell-labs.com/cm/cs/cbook/2ediffs.html) does not list anything for this problem. My best guess is the condition should `<` instead of `>=`.

Answer (score 2):

Code above is fine as long as `pos == 9`  when its passed to that function . If `pos ==10` when its passed then its undefined behaviour and .. you are correct , it should be avoided.

However it may or may not give segmentation fault .

Answer (score 1):

`my_type buffer[SOME_CONSTANT_NAME];` almost always is a bug.

Code like the one you present in the question is the source of the majority of security problems: when the buffer overflows, it invokes undefined behaviour, and that undefined behaviour (if it does not directly crash the program) can frequently be exploited by attackers to execute their own code within your process.

So, my advice is to stay away from all fixed buffer sizes and either use C++'s `std::vector<>` or dynamically allocate enough memory to fit. The Posix 2008 standard makes this quite easy even in C with the `asprintf()` function and friends.